# Сочетание согласованных и несогласованных определений

Tags: определения

Лопатин в § 39 пишет:

Запятая ставится при сочетании согласованных и несогласованных определений (несогласованное определение помещается после согласованного): Между тем в приземистой, с коричневыми стенами зимовке Клюшиных действительно горела слегка увернутая семилинейная лампа (Бел.); Она сняла со стола толстую, с бахромой скатерть и постелила другую, белую (П. Нил.)

А в § 53:

Несогласованные определения, выраженные существительными в форме косвенных падежей с предлогами и относящиеся к нарицательным именам существительным, обособляются:

2) если несогласованные определения включаются в ряды однородных членов вместе с согласованными определениями (определяемое слово в таком случае может и не иметь впереди стоящего определения): Художник, ростом невысокий, юношески легкий вопреки своему росту, в берете и бархатной куртке, прошелся из угла в угол (Бун.).

Почему в первом случае несогласованное определение не обособляется, как во втором случае? Во втором случае ведь тоже последовательность согласованного и несогласованного определения, как и в первом, однако несогласованное определение обособляется, в отличие от первого случая, хотя и там и здесь несогласованное определение идет вслед за согласованным? В чем тут тонкость?

Значит, нельзя написать:

В зимовке Клюшиных, приземистой, с коричневыми стенами (,) горела лампа.

Художник, ростом невысокий, в берете и бархатной куртке () прошелся из угла в угол.

Answer (score 4):

1) В зимовке Клюшиных, приземистой, с коричневыми стенами, горела лампа.

Если ряд определений стоит **после определяемого слова** и начинается с согласованного определения, то весь ряд обособляется обязательно.

2) Художник, ростом невысокий, в берете и бархатной куртке, прошелся из угла в угол.

Здесь запятая в конце ряда является ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЙ, второе определение не может относиться к сказуемому.

Пример:Ко мне подошёл молодой офицер невысокого роста, с лицом отменно некрасивым. 
Первое несогласованное определение может не обособляться, но второе уже обособляется обязательно.

Answer (score 3):

> Почему в первом случае несогласованное определение не обособляется,
>   как во втором случае?.. **В чем тут тонкость?**

В первом случае (§ 39) определяемое слово стоит **после** определений,  во втором (§ 53) -- **до** определений.

> **Значит, нельзя написать:**
>
> В зимовке Клюшиных, приземистой, с коричневыми стенами горела
>   лампа.

**Нельзя.** Нужна запятая после *стенами.*

> Значит, нельзя написать:
>
> Художник, ростом невысокий, в берете и бархатной куртке **(,)** прошелся из
>   угла в угол.

**Можно и с запятой** после *куртки*, **и без запятой.** Зависит от интонации.

В первом случае ***в берете*** и ***(в) куртке*** будут считаться однородными несогласованными определениями (художник *какой?*), во втором -- обстоятельствами (прошёлся *как?*).